# What is underlying framework and programming language that MS powerapps is build upon?

Tags: powerapps

I want to know the underlying framework of microsoft powerapps. Can any one tell on what language or framework is powerapps build upon or share some references.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some investigation. Here is what I've gleaned:

- [PCF components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/custom-controls-overview) for PowerApps are built using Typescript
- If you create a PowerApp, then hit its `read-only` URL*, you will get the "low-code" representation of the app (hint: Lots of .json)
- If you try to hit its `read-only` URL too fast after a change has been published, you'll get an error `container initializing`
- If you open the dev console in browser, you'll get some details as to what api's are called and what elements make up the screen

*To find the read-only url, you'll need to use Flow.

- In Flow, use the `Get Environments as Admin` then the `Get PowerApps as Admin` actions. Look for the `Read-only URL` in the output of the second action.